# laravel delete method in controller redirects to index

Tags: php, laravel

Maybe someone has encountered this.
I only use the API in Laravel, there are no views in it.
I defined "delete" but after calling this routing, I get a 301 redirect to "notifications".

`routes.php`

```php
Route::controller(NotificationController::class)
    ->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'index');
        Route::delete('/{id}', 'destroy');
        Route::delete('/', 'destroyAll');
        Route::put('/{id}', 'markAsRead');
    });
```

`NotificationController.php`

```php
class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return new NotificationResource($request->user()->notifications->sortBy('read_at'));
    }



    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function markAsRead(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        return $request->user()->notifications()->where('id', $id)->first()->markAsRead();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        return $request->user()->notifications()->where('id', $id)->first()->delete();
    }

    /**
     * Remove all notifications from storage.
     */
    public function destroyAll(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->notifications()->delete();
    }
}
```

When i run `DELETE /api/notifications/`
it returns 301 to `GET /api/notifications/`(index in controller).

Anyone knows why?

Interestingly, everything works fine for me locally, it doesn't work on the server.
Clearing the cache or dump-autoload does not help.

UPDATE: I defined routes in `RouteServiceProvider` (simplified version):

```
public function boot() {
    Route::middleware('api')
        ->prefix('api/notifications')
        ->group(base_path('routes/routes.php'));
}
```

UPDATE: output of `php artisan route:list`:

```
GET|HEAD api/notifications ..................NotificationController@index 
DELETE api/notifications/destroyAll .........NotificationController@destroyAll 
DELETE api/notifications/{id}................NotificationController@destroy 
PUT api/notifications/{id}...................NotificationController@markAsRead
```

Comment: Try `$request->user()->notifications->delete();`

Comment: Notifications is removed on my local machine. Problem is that 'destroyAll'  is not even hit. When i return some string in that method it doesn't return that string.

Comment: Which version of Laravel is this?  `routes.php` was 5.2 and earlier I think, vs `web.php` and `api.php` after that.  Routes in `api.php` are automatically defined under `/api` - but in old `routes.php` you would have to explicity define that prefix, which yours does not.  It seems like the routes you've shown are not for `/api/notifications/`, so where is that route defined?

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` show?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved!**

The problem was "slash" at the end of url.

When i request `GET api/notifications` not `GETapi/notifications/`,
everything works.

Sorry for bothering you.
Cheers

Answer (score -2):

To resolve this issue: Correct the code that you provided as fellow:
1- Because you have Route / and DELETE Method it will saved this route and all words after /.
that means you can't set 2 route for same PATH
so change the route like this:

```
Route::controller(NotificationController::class)
    ->middleware(['auth:sanctum'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/item', 'index');
        Route::delete('/item/{id}', 'destroy');
        Route::delete('/all', 'destroyAll');
        Route::put('/item/{id}', 'markAsRead');
    });
```

Comment: You can have more routes with the same path as long as their methods/verbs are different. See the Laravel documentation on [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: And why is redirectig when instead it should return 404 or `index`?

Comment: Turns out 'GET /' gives me redirest to self.